# extjs stateful grid remove sort

Tags: gridview, extjs, stateful

I have a problem with statefull grid. I do not want to save the sort state but I do want to save all other options (column position, column width, grouping etc.)

For now I have tried this with stateEvents option, but it saves whole state of grid when the even fires.

Is there any option to exclude sort state from saving??

Part of the grid config:

```
this.gridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                id:'grid'+this.id,
                region:region,
                layout:'fit',
                stateful:true,
                stateEvents: ['columnmove', 'columnresize', 'groupchange', 'bodyresize'],
                loadMask:true,
                split:true,
                store: this.stores['root'+this.id],
                cm: this.getRootColumnModel(),
                sm: this.getRootSelectionModel(),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply override grid's `applyState` method (and delete `sort` state in it):

```
this.gridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    // ...,
    // ...,
    applyState: function(state) {
        if (state) {
            var newState = Ext.apply({}, state);
            delete newState['sort'];
            Ext.apply(this, newState );
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not my solution, appears to have come from the Sencha support team, the example works.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dlc

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?294920